# Reading a large text file faster

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a large text file as fast as possible.

- Lines not beginning with '!' are passed over.
- Lines with 8 CSV have their last value removed.
- There will never be a ',' in a value (didn't need to use opencsv).
- Everything is added to a long string that is decoded later.

So this is my code

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Documents\\ais_messages1.3.txt")); 
String line, aisLines="", cvsSplitBy = ",";
try {
   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      if(line.charAt(0) == '!') {
         String[] cols = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
         if(cols.length>=8) {
            line = ""; 
            for(int i=0; i<cols.length-1; i++) {
               if(i == cols.length-2) {
                  line = line + cols[i]; 
               } else {
                  line = line + cols[i] + ","; 
               } 
            }
            aisLines += line + "\n";
         } else {
            aisLines += line + "\n"; 
         }
      }
   }
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So right now it reads 36890 rows in 14 seconds. I also tried an InputStreamReader:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Documents\\ais_messages1.3.txt"));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

and it took the same amount of time. Is there a faster way to read a large text file (100,000 or 1,000,000 rows) ?

Comment: use a `StringBuilder` for string concatenation

Comment: Profile your code and see where it's spending its time right now, then see if you can make the slow parts faster.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when there are more than 8 values? Your code is always removing the last item in such a case. Is that really how it should behave?

Comment: @SpiderPig yeah typically the csv has 7 values, but there's an error where it might have an 8th value which breaks the decoder.

Comment: just make sure you know what will happens if there are 9 values. "taking the first 7" is different from "removing the last"

Comment: @Jacky Cheng Good point ! I'm working with a regulated CSV format, so hopefully this will not occur, but it's important to be aware of :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop trying to build up `aisLines` as a big String. Use an `ArrayList<String>` that you append the lines on to. That takes 0.6% the time as your method on my machine. (This code processes 1,000,000 simple lines in 0.75 seconds.) And it will reduce the effort needed to process the data later, as it'll already be split up by lines.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
List<String> aisLines = new ArrayList<String>();
String line, cvsSplitBy = ",";
try {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.charAt(0) == '!') {
            String[] cols = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            if(cols.length>=8) {
                line = "";
                for(int i=0; i<cols.length-1; i++) {
                    if(i == cols.length-2) {
                        line = line + cols[i];
                    } else {
                        line = line + cols[i] + ",";
                    }
                }
                aisLines.add(line);
            } else {
                aisLines.add(line);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you really want a big `String` at the end (because you're interfacing with someone else's code, or whatever), it'll still be faster to convert the `ArrayList` back into a single string, than to do what you were doing.

Comment: it seems like the splitting and re-combine are excessive work? Maybe 
`if(StringUtils.countMatches(line, ",") >= 7)`   and `String shortenLine = line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(","));` would work better?

Comment: Awesome, yeah the decoder needs a giant string split up with regex =, but ill put everything into an arraylist and then turn the arrlist into a giant string after the file is read.

Answer (score 1):

As the most consuming operation is IO the most efficient way is to split threads for parsing and reading:

```
   private static void readFast(String filePath) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    List<String> parsed = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            final String l = line;
            executor.submit(() -> {
                if (l.charAt(0) == '!') {
                    parsed.add(parse(l));
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MINUTES);


    String result = parsed.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

For my pc it has taken 386ms vs 10787ms with the slow one

Comment: I'm trying this solution out, running into issues with (parse(l)); (method not found)

Answer (score 0):

You can use single thread reads your large csv file and multiple threads parse all lines. The way I do is using `Producer-Consumer` pattern and BlockingQueue.

**Producer**

Making one Producer Thread which is only responsible for reading the lines of your csv file, and stores lines into BlockingQueue. The producer side does not do anything else.

**Consumers**

Making multiple Consumer Threads, pass the same BlockingQueue object into your consumers.  Implementing **time consuming work** in your Consumer Thread class.

**The following code provide you an idea of solving problem, not the solution.**
I was implemented this using python and it works much faster than using a single thread do everything. The language is not java, but the theory behind is the same.

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue

QUEUE_SIZE = 2000


def produce(file_queue, row_queue,):

    while not file_queue.empty():
        src_file = file_queue.get()
        zip_reader = gzip.open(src_file, 'rb')

        try:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(zip_reader, delimiter=SDP_DELIMITER)

            for row in csv_reader:
                new_row = process_sdp_row(row)
                if new_row:
                    row_queue.put(new_row)
        finally:
            zip_reader.close()


def consume(row_queue):
    '''processes all rows, once queue is empty, break the infinit loop'''
    while True:
        try:
            # takes a row from queue and process it
            pass
        except multiprocessing.TimeoutError as toe:
            print "timeout, all rows have been processed, quit."
            break
        except Queue.Empty:
            print "all rows have been processed, quit."
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print "critical error"
            print e
            break


def main(args):

    file_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    row_queue = multiprocessing.Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)

    file_queue.put(file1)
    file_queue.put(file2)
    file_queue.put(file3)

    # starts 3 producers
    for i in xrange(4):
        producer = multiprocessing.Process(target=produce,args=(file_queue,row_queue))
        producer.start()

    # starts 1 consumer
    consumer = multiprocessing.Process(target=consume,args=(row_queue,))
    consumer.start()

    # blocks main thread until consumer process finished
    consumer.join()

    # prints statistics results after consumer is done

    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: I have little experience with multi threading, but will read into more :) Thank you for the help.